# Why won't my JavaScript submit forms?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Basically, I'm trying to submit several form elements using JavaScript. Here is the code for the forms themselves:

```
<form method="post" action="opmod.php" name="gender">
<p class="type">Gender:</p>
<input list="genderList" required>
<datalist  id="genderList">
    <option value="Male"></option>
    <option value="Female"></option>
</datalist>
</input>
</form>
<form method="post" action="opmod.php" name="race">
<p class="type">Race:</p>
<input list="raceList" required>
<datalist  id="raceList">
    <option value="White"></option>
    <option value="Black"></option>
    <option value="Asian"></option>
    <option value="Hispanic"></option>
    <option value="American Indian"></option>
    <option value="Other"></option>
</datalist>
</input>
</form>
```

However, when I use this script to submit it, nothing happens:

```
submitInp=function(){
    document.forms["state"].submit();
    document.forms["age"].submit();
    document.forms["gender"].submit();
    document.forms["race"].submit();
    document.cookie="infoGiven=true;expires="+(today.getTime() + 60 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)+";path=/";
}
```

I have also tried it by adding "ids" to the form elements, getting those elements with "document.getElementById", and submitting them, but nothing works. What is my problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: As soon as the first form ("state") submits, the page will navigate to `opmod.php` via POST (assuming that's the action and method for that form). No other forms will be submitted because the page has navigated away

Comment: Are you sure you don't want just one form including all the various inputs? You'd just need to add `name` attributes to the `<input>` elements

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one form instead of using multiple which will navigate to `opmod.php` after you submit the first form.

```
<form method="post" action="opmod.php" name="data" id="data">
    //Put your inputs here
    //state inputs
    //age inputs
    //gender inputs
    //race inputs
</form>
```

and in your javascript just use:

```
document.getElementById("data").submit();
```

Comment: What would this get submitted? What would $_POST["data"] return?

Comment: @Damphair in your `inputs` add a `name`. For example: name="genderList".  Try to `print_r` or `vardump` `$_POST` after you submit your form. so you will see if the data is submitted.

Comment: I've tried echoing $_POST['state'] after putting the input in and submitting, but I'm not getting anything; just an error saying that $_POST['state'] is not defined. Why is that? I've added the names just like you said.

Comment: @Damphair Please try to `var_dump` or `print_r` first the  `$_POST` to see if there is a data. and post the output